# need help on a trigger on custom object to get values of some fields from case

Tags: trigger, case

I have written a trigger on custom object to copy values of some fields from case objects. Trigger is saved successfully but when i try to create related problem from case it is not copying any fields value.

Trigger :

```
trigger UpdateProblemTicketOwner on SC_Problem_Management__c (before insert,before update)
{    
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert)
    {
        Set<Id> CsId = new Set<Id>();
        for (SC_Problem_Management__c obj : Trigger.new)
        {
            CsId.add(obj.Case__c);
        }

        Map<Id,Case> Cases = new Map<Id,Case>([SELECT Id From Case Where Id IN :CsId ]);

        for (SC_Problem_Management__c obj : Trigger.new)
        {
            Case l = Cases.get(obj.Case__c);
            if (l == null)
            {
                continue; //skips this iteration of the loop
            }
            obj.Priority__c = string.valueof(Case.Priority);
            obj.Title__c = string.valueof(Case.Subject);
            obj.Product__c = string.valueof(Case.Product__c);
            obj.Component__c = string.valueof(Case.Componet__c);
            obj.Feature__c = string.valueof(Case.Feature__c);
            obj.Status__c = string.valueof(Case.Status);
            obj.Description__c = string.valueof(Case.Description__c);

        }

    }

}
```

Please let me know if i'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

first, remove `null` values from set of Case Ids:

```
Set<Id> CsId = new Set<Id>();
for (SC_Problem_Management__c obj : Trigger.new)
{
    CsId.add(obj.Case__c);
}
CsId.remove(null);
```

second, you want to query field on Case soql in order to have  their values:

```
Map<Id,Case> Cases = new Map<Id,Case>([SELECT Id, Priority, Subject, Product__c, Componet__c, Feature__c, Status, Description__c  From Case Where Id IN :CsId ]);
```

third, in order to access field from got `Case` by `obj.Case__c`, you have to use `l.` varibale, as you declared it as `Case l = Cases.get(obj.Case__c);`

---

making all that, your code will look like:

```
trigger UpdateProblemTicketOwner on SC_Problem_Management__c (before insert,before update)
{    
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert)
    {
        Set<Id> CsId = new Set<Id>();
        for (SC_Problem_Management__c obj : Trigger.new)
        {
            CsId.add(obj.Case__c);
        }
        CsId.remove(null);

        Map<Id,Case> Cases = new Map<Id,Case>([SELECT Id, Priority, Subject, Product__c, Componet__c, Feature__c, Status, Description__c  From Case Where Id IN :CsId ]);

        for (SC_Problem_Management__c obj : Trigger.new)
        {
            if(Cases.containsKey(obj.Case__c)){
                Case l = Cases.get(obj.Case__c);
                obj.Priority__c = string.valueof(l.Priority);
                obj.Title__c = string.valueof(l.Subject);
                obj.Product__c = string.valueof(l.Product__c);
                obj.Component__c = string.valueof(l.Componet__c);
                obj.Feature__c = string.valueof(l.Feature__c);
                obj.Status__c = string.valueof(l.Status);
                obj.Description__c = string.valueof(l.Description__c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Congrats on 10k!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all field that you need to your SOQL query.

```
trigger UpdateProblemTicketOwner on SC_Problem_Management__c (before insert,before update)
{    
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert)
    {
        Set<Id> CsId = new Set<Id>();
        for (SC_Problem_Management__c obj : Trigger.new)
        {
            CsId.add(obj.Case__c);
        }

        Map<Id,Case> Cases = new Map<Id,Case>([SELECT Id,Priority,Subject,Product__c,Componet__c,Feature__c,Status,Description__c From Case Where Id IN :CsId ]);

        for (SC_Problem_Management__c obj : Trigger.new)
        {
            Case caseObj = Cases.get(obj.Case__c);
            if (l == null)
            {
                continue; //skips this iteration of the loop
            }
            obj.Priority__c = caseObj.Priority;
            obj.Title__c = caseObj.Subject;
            obj.Product__c = caseObj.Product__c;
            obj.Component__c = caseObj.Componet__c;
            obj.Feature__c = caseObj.Feature__c;
            obj.Status__c = caseObj.Status;
            obj.Description__c = caseObj.Description__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Oleksandr & Rahul, I have tried same code mentioned by you it is still not working as expected. When i click on new of SC_Problem_Management__c it is showing me all fields blank except case number.

Comment: @SnehalGaware did you save the record?

Comment: i can not save the records as these fields are mandatory on custom object and needs to be populated from Case.

Comment: as these fields are mandatory you need to provide values to it, the trigger will update values after the record is saved into the backend, I would suggest you make it not required as ultimately you are filling then via the trigger, also if anyone edit those field, trigger will override those changes and again copy data from case.

Comment: can we have all these before saving the record on layout, like along with case number, all there fields should get populated. is there any possibility?

Comment: In that case you need to override the standard edit/new action with a standard controller visualforce page.

Comment: Another option is to keep them non required at insert and required on edit using validation rule.

Comment: if i make them non required, values will be displayed after save only. I need to view them before saving that record just like case number.

Comment: @SnehalGaware You can override standard new/edit page using VF page/lightning component, on that VF/Lightning Cmp you can put all fields needed and build functionality to populate case details in your fields. These links might be helpful [Use Lightning CMP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_action_overrides.htm)/[Use VF page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_customize_override.htm)